# Load 2 images one after each using Glide android

Tags: android, imageview, android-glide

I am using glide image loading library to load image in view pager.

I want to load two URLs one after another in same `imageview` but I am not able to achieve, I tried below code

```
Glide.with(Activity.this)
        .load(thumbnail_url)
        .asBitmap().centerCrop()
        .dontTransform()
        .error(R.drawable.thumb_err)
        .into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(viewHolder.imgCoverImage) {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(Bitmap drawable, GlideAnimation anim) {
                super.onResourceReady(drawable, anim);
            }
        });

Glide.with(Activity.this)
        .load(actual_url)
        .asBitmap().centerCrop()
        .dontTransform()
        .error(R.drawable.thumb_err)
        .into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(viewHolder.imgCoverImage) {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(Bitmap drawable, GlideAnimation anim) {
                super.onResourceReady(drawable, anim);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a listener to the first image and then load the second one in onResourceReady:

```
.listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
         @Override
         public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
             return false;
         }

         @Override
         public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
             // load second image here
             return false;
         }
     }).into(viewHolder.imgCoverImage);
```

Note that if you're trying to load a thumbnail before loading the full image, Glide has made this doable in their newest release